# aggression factor vs aggression frequency

Tags: poker-tools, pokertracker

So I was taking a look at PokerTracker's LeakTracker and noticed that my overall aggression factor needs improvement because it is too high (2.41). But it says my aggression frequency is good (51.25%). This confuses me because from what it says in the description they both seem to be the same thing so I'm not sure how I can be doing one too often yet the other properly?
what is the difference between the two?

Also I am playing low stakes limit holdem

Comment: Good question and welcome to the site.   I would not use a tools where terms are not clearly defined.

Comment: Good point Papparazzi, I think the terms could definitely be explained more clearly (See the link to the Stats guide in my answer). They are only useful if you can understand them!

Answer (score 4):

Based on [PokerTracker's Stats Guide](https://www.pokertracker.com/guides/PT3/general/statistical-reference-guide), the *Aggression Factor* (**AF**) is:

> A measure of how aggressive or passive the player is on a particular street.

And the *Aggression Frequency* (**AFq**) is:

> The measure of how frequently the player made aggressive actions preflop or on the flop, turn or river.

If you look at the formulas, the key difference is that the **AF** takes into account the *Aggressiveness Vs Passiveness* of the player, focusing on how often they will *call* whereas the **AFq** measures the player's *Aggressive Actions* in all contexts (PF|F|T|R).

[This Forum](https://www.pokertracker.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=1272&start=0) helped me come to this conclusion but the below formulas tell the full story:

**AF**:

```
( Times bet PF|F|T|R + times raised PF|F|T|R ) / ( Times called PF|F|T|R )
```

**AFq**:

```
[ (Times Bet PF|F|T|R + Times Raised PF|F|T|R ) / 
(Times Bet PF|F|T|R + Times Raised PF|F|T|R + Times Called PF|F|T|R
 + Times Folded PF|F|T|R) ] * 100
```

Comment: To apply that to Ezra's particular situation, if he wanted to leave the AFq unchanged but have the AF decrease, he could continue to bet and raise the same but also add more calls in certain spots.  Whether or not that's the right thing to do is another matter; I don't think there's any perfect number to shoot for with these statistics--you just need everything to jive together within your style of play and the types of people you're going up against.